# Changing the Lens.OrthographicSize (Cinemachine) Value in Unity in a Script

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, cinemachine

so im very new to Unity.
I make a 2D Plattformer and try to Zoom out when you Press 'Tab'.

I like to change the OrthographicSize from my VirtualCamera via script, but cant figur out how.. any ideas?

Camera follows the Player.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution!

```
using Cinemachine; //to use cinemachine

public CinemachineVirtualCamera vcam; //to assign cam

vcam.m_Lens.OrthographicSize = 20; //to access cam, Lens and then OrthograhicSize
```